# Pandas merge giving wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok
I have gone through some blogs related to this topic - but I am still getting the same problem. I have two dataframes. Both have a column X which have SHA2 values in them. It contains hex strings.

Example (Dataframe lookup)

```
X,Y
000000000E000394574D69637264736F66742057696E646F7773204861726477,7
0000000080000000000000090099000000040005000000000000008F2A000010,7
000000020000000000000000777700010000000000020000000040C002004600,24
0000005BC614437F6BE049237FA1DDD2083B5BA43A10175E4377A59839DC2B64,7
```

Example (Dataframe source)

```
X,Z
000000000E000394574D69637264736F66742057696E646F7773204861726477,'blah'
0000000080000000000000090099000000040005000000000000008F2A000010,'blah blah'
000000020000000000000000777700010000000000020000000040C002004600,'dummy'
```

etc.

So now I am doing

```
lookup['X'] = lookup['X'].astype(str)
source['X'] = source['X'].astype(str)
source['newcolumn'] = source.merge(lookup, on='X', how='inner')['Y']
```

The source has 160,000 rows and the lookup has around 500,000 rows.

Now, when the operation finishes, I get newcolumn but the values are wrong.
I have made sure that they are not being picked up from duplicate values of X, because there are no duplicate X in either table.

So, this is really making me feel dumb and gave me quite a pain in my live systems. Can anyone suggest what is the problem ?

I have now replaced the call with

```
def getReputation(lookupDF,value,lookupcolumn,default):
    lookupRows = lookupDF.loc[lookupDF['X']==value]
    if lookupRows.shape[0]>0:
        return lookupRows[lookupcolumn].values[0]
    else:
        return default

source['newcolumn'] = source.apply(lambda x: getReputation(lookup,x['X'],'Y',-1),axis=1)
```

This code works - but obviously it is BAD code and takes a horrible long time. I can multiprocess it - but the question remains. WHY is the merge failing ?

Thanks for your help
Rgds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method in this case:

first set 'X' as index in the `lookup` DF:

```
In [58]: lookup.set_index('X', inplace=True)

In [59]: lookup
Out[59]:
                                                                   Y
X
000000000E000394574D69637264736F66742057696E646F7773204861726477   7
0000000080000000000000090099000000040005000000000000008F2A000010   7
000000020000000000000000777700010000000000020000000040C002004600  24
0000005BC614437F6BE049237FA1DDD2083B5BA43A10175E4377A59839DC2B64   7

In [60]: df['Y'] = df.X.map(lookup.Y)

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
                                                                  X          Z   Y
0  000000000E000394574D69637264736F66742057696E646F7773204861726477       blah   7
1  0000000080000000000000090099000000040005000000000000008F2A000010  blah blah   7
2  000000020000000000000000777700010000000000020000000040C002004600      dummy  24
```

Actually your code is working properly for your sample DFs:

```
In [68]: df.merge(lookup, on='X', how='inner')
Out[68]:
                                                                  X          Z   Y
0  000000000E000394574D69637264736F66742057696E646F7773204861726477       blah   7
1  0000000080000000000000090099000000040005000000000000008F2A000010  blah blah   7
2  000000020000000000000000777700010000000000020000000040C002004600      dummy  24
```

So check whether you have the same data and dtypes in the `X` column in both DFs

Comment: Hey - thanks for that comment - I will check map and get back asap.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks. And NO - I did not change anything else. So there is some problem with the merge. May be I should report a bug. And yes I make sure that the dtype and data is the same before merge. It works on these few lines - but not on the real data set which are quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you might have duplicate values on column X on the lookup data frame. It is due to the indexing of fields and the below snippet will produce the right results.

```py
output = source.merge(lookup, on='X', how='inner')
```

In case if you want to create a new column, either it should not have any duplicates on the right df or the indexes needs to be adjusted accordingly. If you're sure there are no duplicate values, compare the indexes from the above snippet and your snippet for better understanding and try resetting the indexes before merging.